# Aspnetboilerplate SQL Server migration primary key incremented by 10000

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key, database-migration, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.Net boilerplate project. I have come across a very strange behaviour that **in some tables in the database, primary key value is sometimes incremented by a factor of 10000**. For example the last id is **4321, the next is 14321**. What my guess is that it is the **EF migration** which increments the key value to avoid possible foriegn key conflict. But increment of 10000 is too high. Can someone please help in this case or highlight the reason or the cause of this problem.

***PS. I am new to ABP.**

I have looked around in the code to see if I can find something but nothing clear.

Comment: have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Some times it can be due to failed Transactions, as Abp uses UnitOfWork, any failed/exception transaction is not committed and those ids are skipped. You can Test this also.

Comment: this is what I also thought of and this can be one of the reason of non-used keys but still the number 10000 is too much. I don't want to waste that many ids as the database is growing very rapidly.